# How to identify element in iPad - Appium

Tags: xcode, selenium, appium-ios

I am new to appium and I have to identify an element, I have only one attribute there i.e `value`, Can anyone help me how to identify that element. The image gives the details of the element and i want to identify this element and use it in my automation code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, Open Safari, press Command + , to open Safari Settings.
Open Advanced tab and enable "Show developer menu"

Launch your hybrid/web AUT, Connect your iPhone / iPad to Mac, open Safari, Open Developer Menu, select your device and AUT to inspect elements.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Appium Inspector to identify the elements in iPad app.

Steps to get the element details from Appium Inspector

1. Start Appium server
2. Click on Start Inspector Session
3. Enter the capabilities
4. Click on start session button

On inspector window you get the screenshot of the page open from there we can get the element details